# How do I build .deb for a ROS package?

Tags: ros, package, deb, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As ROS calls its software modules "packages" this might be a bit confusing: This question is *not* about compiling a ROS package but rather building the `.deb` archive (also called "package" in ubuntu/debian terminology).

We have found a bug in a ROS package and found a solution. Thus, we built the ROS package/stack via catkin and now need to deploy it. As the CMakeLists.txt of this particular ROS package (i.e., rqt) and even the entire stack does not contain CPack instructions there seems no simple way to get a ".deb" out of it.

What is the simplest way to get a ".deb" file for a ROS package that should utlimately replace the original ROS package? Or is there an alternative yet easy way to  deploy our fix? (Note that our fix is not an official fix, thus official build farms are not an option.)

I should add that preferably I do not want to change the CMakeLists.txt of this ROS package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163281/how-do-i-build-.deb-for-a-ros-package?/) by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2014-05-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should really try to get your fix accepted into the upstream repository, and released through the official build farm.

It's possible to build debs by setting up a release repository using bloom and then manually invoking the deb build process, but if you install those debs, there's no guarantee that they'll persist across upgrades. For example, if the upstream rqt releases a new version with a higher version number than the deb you build, it will automatically replace your custom deb when someone runs 'apt-get upgrade'

The other alternative is not to try to build debs at all; just add your custom rqt package to your catkin workspace, and it will always override the system version.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2014-05-09**:
Thanks for your answer. I already added an issue to their bug tracker. And we would very much like to use the official releases. Meanwhile we need a fix that can be easily deployed. Deploying a catkin workspace seems not that straightforward.

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2014-05-09**:
Second, the package I need to fix is rqt. If you overlay the catkin workspace for this particular package it will still fail as the "rqt" python script calls more or less (freely translated) "rospack find rqt_gui_core", which is a different package. Afterwards the non-overlayed path is used.

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2014-05-09**:
Finally, we cannot simply use older versions as these are not in the ROS repository anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To bulid your own debian packages is possible, but will take some learning.

There are some simple [tutorials](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html) but they won't catch all the corner cases.

The debian guide is [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html)

A quicker solution is probably to use a tool like [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-05-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2014-12-02**:
checkinstall is indeed a good "solution" for such cases.